# What is the correct syntax for the Macro Assembler AS ORG directive?

Tags: assembly, 6800

I am using the Macro Assembler AS for the Motorola 6800. How do I tell the assembler that my 8K ROM is located at address `0xE000`?

This is the relevant section in the user manual:
http://john.ccac.rwth-aachen.de:8000/as/as_EN.html#sect_3_2_1_

I have tried:

`ORG $E000`

`ORG 0xE000`

`ORG 0E000h`

`ORG 57344`

But I always get the error:

```
$ asl -cpu 6800 test.s
Assembling test.s
PASS 1
> > > test.s(11):5: error: unknown instruction
test.s(125)

0.00 seconds assembly time

    125 lines source file
      1 pass
      1 error
      0 warnings
```

Just writing `ORG` with no parameter gives no error.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by putting a tab indentation before the ORG